# Sequential dialog execution in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to use a JQuery Dialog to confirm the removing of different records from different tables, so it's a div that is being referenced from different places in the code (reusing dialog to confirm different operation).
I'm using this example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Since with every call, it has to confirm a very different action, I can't just put the code to execute inside the callback for the Ok or Cancel buttons of the Dialog option buttons{}

I would like to have something like VB's MsgBox with a return value indicating the button pressed (whether it was 'Ok', 'Accept' or 'close'...).
Something like this:

```
if ( $(target_dialog).dialog('open') == 'Ok'){
    // Do something awesome
}else if( $(target_dialog).dialog('open') == 'Cancel') {
    // Do something not that awesome
}
```

Thanks for your help.

### EDIT: It's something like the JS confirm() example here( http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm ), but I don't want it to be a pop up, but a customizable and flexible jqueryui dialog.

EDIT2: Just like @vishwanath suggests

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
//height, modal, width... settings
buttons : {
    "OK": function() { 
        // here is the magic
            action = $(this).data('action');
        var actionToPerform = actions[action];
        actionToPerform.call(this);
        // end of magic
        $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
    }, 
    Cancel: function() {
        console.log("non awesome stuff here");
        $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
    }
}
});


var actions = {
action1 : function(){
    console.log(''Do action1 stuff here);
}, 
action2 : function(){
    console.log('Do action2 stuff here');
}
// and so on...
}
```

And from different parents different actions for different answers can be performed.

```
$( '#dlgConfirm' ).data('action', 'action1').dialog( 'open' );
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if people who downvote tell the reasons why?
We are learning here, it's not that smart clicking without justifying.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use custom options of jquery UI.

As per following create a mode custom option, which will be set dynamically at the time of dialogue creation. Check for that option in your click handler and use the mode to pick up the right action depending upon your mode.

```
var mode = 'edit'; //Set this dynamically
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    height : 140,
    modal : true,
    mode : mode,
    buttons : [ {
        text : "OK",
        click : function(event) {
            var mode = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('option', mode);
            var actionToPerform = actions[mode];
            actionToPerfom.call(this, event);
        }
    }, 
    {
        text : "Cancel",
        click : function(event, ui) {
            console.log("non awesome stuff here");
        }
    } ]
});


var actions = {
    edit : function(){
        console.log(''Do Edit stuff here);
    }, 
    delete : function(){
        console.log('Do delete stuff here');
    }

}
```

Comment: This is precisely the problem, I have several tabbed widgets, with tables on each, each row has several buttons with actions that require confirmation (some of them involve deleting or updating fields, from different tables.
So I just can't put specific code in those handlers you mention, with this approach I would have to create a different div for EVERY SINGLE confirmation dialog.
I need some generic confirmation that I could use from all code, that's why I mention the MsgBox example from VB.

Thanks for your answer!  :)

Comment: Added answer with better approach.

Comment: Thank you, I did this approach, but instead of passing the data to the dialog via custom options, i did it using .data().
So it's more readable (i guess):
/* Context of accounts configuration*/ 
    $('#dlgConfirm').data('action', 'delAccount').dialog('open');
/* another context*/
    $('#dlgConfirm').data('action', 'updateAccount').dialog('open');

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promises (aka "deferred objects") to emulate a function that returns a value once the dialog is closed.  Combine this with a modal dialog box to ensure the user can't do anything else until that dialog is closed:

```
function myConfirm() {
    my def = $.Deferred();
    $('#myDiv').dialog({
       modal: true,
       buttons: [ {
           'ok': def.resolve,
           'cancel': def.reject
       } ]
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

(add code for parameterising the dialog to suit)

Then:

```
myConfirm().done(function() {
    // user pressed OK
}).fail(function() {
    // user pressed Cancel
});
```